# JQuery AJAX to PHP issue with CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a php API that I can use JQuery to post to in order to make a Phonegap app. I keep running into a problem with CORS (I think) when I try to use the AJAX call

Here is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/login",
    data: { 
        user: username, 
        pass: password
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

And here are the headers I'm setting in the PHP file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with');
```

Every time I run the ajax call I get the same errors returned in the console:

```
POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/login 500 (Internal Server Error) 
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send
o.extend.ajax
login
onclick
```

The Ajax call is inside a function called 'login' that is being run on a button click, which I think accounts for the last two lines of the error message, but I don't understand the rest. Also, If I add a contentType: "application/json" to the ajax call the error message changes to

```
OPTIONS http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send
o.extend.ajax
login
onclick
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/login. Invalid HTTP status code 500
```

I don't know if it matters, but I'm running it on a AWS EC2 running Amazon Linux and a LAMP stack which I set up following these instructions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

The remaining hair that I havn't pulled out yet says thanks for any help anyone can give. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to CORS. Status code 500 means something is wrong in server. Check your server logs for any error.

Comment: You were right. Nothing to do with CORS. I was including the port in the host name when I created my database call. I was able to get data out of the database with the call, but it was also throwing an error to the server logs. When I required the config file the require was throwing the 500 error. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.